# Is there a better approach to filter data on a GET call like the following? (NodeJs & MongoDb)

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, sorting, promise

So I have an array of users like the following:

```
let person1 = {
  username: 'test',
  userId: '11',
  log: [
    {
      _id: '5f2b29f501ec0e46c7f2944c',
      date: 'Tue Feb 02 2010',
      duration: 34,
      description: 'tennis 2010',
    },
    {
      _id: '5f2b2a888878e94706a6f072',
      date: 'Fri Feb 02 2001',
      duration: 23,
      description: 'tennis',
    },
    {
      _id: '5f2b2a8d8878e94706a6f073',
      date: 'Sat Feb 02 2002',
      duration: 23,
      description: 'tennis',
    },
    {
      _id: '5f2b2a918878e94706a6f074',
      date: 'Sun Feb 02 2003',
      duration: 23,
      description: 'tennis',
    },
  ],
};
```

I would like to make a call using `GET /api/exercise/log?{userId}[&from][&to][&limit]`where [] params are optional and {} is required.

so if the dates in of each log is:

`'Sat Feb 02 2002'`

`'Sat Feb 02 2003'`

`'Sat Feb 02 2004'`

`'Sat Feb 02 2005'`

and my call is `/api/exercise/log?userId=11&from=2003-03-01` The result should be the logs that were logged on

`'Sat Feb 02 2004'`

`'Sat Feb 02 2005'`

Everything below is working well and it's giving me what I want, I just would like to know if there is a better practice for filtering using queries.

```
app.get('/api/exercise/log?', (req, res) => {
  const { userId, from, to, limit } = req.query;

  //   if userId was entered
  if (userId) {
    //   find person
    Exercise.findOne({ userId })
      .then((person) => {
        let result = [];
        // if "from" was entered
        if (from) {
          // return only the date that are greater than "from"
          person.log.map((exercise) => {
            if (new Date(exercise.date).valueOf() >= new Date(from).valueOf()) {
              result.push(exercise);
            }
          });
          return result;
        } else {
          // else return all the logs
          return person.log;
        }
      })
      .then((logs) => {
        let result = [];
        // if "to" was entered
        if (to) {
          // return only the date that are less than "to"
          logs.map((exercise) => {
            if (new Date(exercise.date).valueOf() <= new Date(to).valueOf()) {
              result.push(exercise);
            }
          });
          return result;
        } else {
          // else return all the logs
          return logs;
        }
      })
      .then((logs) => {
        let result = [];

        // if limit was entered
        if (limit) {
          for (let i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
            result.push(logs[i]);
          }
          return result;
        } else {
          // if limit wasn't entered, return all the logs
          return logs;
        }
      })
      .then((logs) => {
         // render result
        res.send(logs);
      }).catch(err=>{
        // if user doesn't exist
        res.send('Unknown User')
      })
  } else {
         // if userId wasen't entered
    res.send('unknown user');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first choice should be phrasing your query to return just the data of interest but let's stick with the indicated approach.

After finding `person`, all the processing is entirely synchronous, therefore the three `.then(logs => ....)` stages can be merged into the opening `.then(person => ...)` stage allowing you to write something like this:

```
app.get('/api/exercise/log?', (req, res) => {
    const { userId, from, to, limit } = req.query;
    if (userId) {
        Exercise.findOne({ userId }) // find person
        .then(person => {
            let filtered = person.log.filter((exercise, i) => {
                let exerciseDate = new Date(exercise.date);
                let from_ = from ? exerciseDate >= new Date(from) : true; // boolean for `from` condition
                let to_ = to ? exerciseDate <= new Date(to).valueOf() : true; // boolean for `to` condition
                let limit_ = i < limit; // boolean for `limit` condition
                return from_ && to_ && limit_; // will return `true` only if all three conditions are met. 
            });
            res.send(filtered);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.send('Unknown User');
        });
    } else {
        res.send('unknown user');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Roamer, however, the "from, to, limit" variables are optional. In the code you suggested, if the user doesn't provide one of the optional variables, there will be no logs! Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: As written, `from_` and `to_` default to `true` if falsy and the effect should be the same as in the question (rightly or wrongly). I forgot to apply a default value to `limit_`, which is possibly a little trickier depending on the behaviour you want. Do you want a limit of zero to mean zero results, or all results?